# Executing php program in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

[image]I installed php eclipse in my system i wrote sample php program and try to run it i'm getting error like this

> Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\xampp\php" (in directory "C:\Program Files\xampp\php\www\Hello world"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Answer (score 1):

Try naming your projects without spaces & installing XAMPP somewhere other then in Program Files like on the root C:

`C:\xampp\php\www\HelloWorld`

Most command line programs (EG:The launcher in this case) have problems with spaces in files & folder names, including the `/Program Files/` directory.

Or in eclipse change the path to php.exe to `C:\PROGRA~1\xampp\php`

Comment: When i debug my program as php script its working fine but when i run as php webpage its throwing error like 'Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 404
localhost
8/5/2011 3:43:46 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1